# Correct way to load middleware for rails and rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rails-api

So... I have a bit of a conundrum.

I've written some rack middleware, it's stored on disk at `app/middleware/eat_bacon.rb`, it looks something like

```
module Middleware
  class EatBacon
    def initialize(app)
      @app = app
    end

    def call(env)
      Thread.current[:mouth] = 'Bacon'
      @app.call(env)
    end
  end
end
```

I'm trying to load / use some middleware in a rails-api (rails 3.2.19)

In my `config/application.rb` I've gotten the middleware to load in two different ways, one way works when running the app, the other way works for rspec

#### Works for running app

```
config.middleware.insert_before 0, 'Middleware::EatBacon'
```

but when I run rspec, I get

> /Volumes/HardDrive/Me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@bacon/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:230:in `block in constantize': uninitialized constant Middleware (NameError)

#### Works for RSpec

```
config.after_initialize do
  config.middleware.insert_before 0, 'Middleware::EatBacon'
end
```

But now the middleware is not loaded when the application runs, ie `Thread.current[:mouth]` never gets bacon

Seems weird to have to implement this differently in config/environments/test.rb and config/environments/production.rb, but I guess thats what I'll end up doing unless someone has a better idea

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The way I solved this was to first move the middleware to the `lib` folder:

```
lib/middleware/eats_bacon.rb
```

AND Then, in `config/application.rb` I added a `require_relative`, so that file now looks like

```
...

Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)
require_relative '../lib/middleware/eats_bacon.rb'

module BaconEaterApp
  class Application < Rails::Application

...
```

Then at the bottom of that file

```
...

# Middleware
config.middleware.insert_before 0, 'Middleware::EatBacon'

...
```